# Living in Albania for the past seven years with a driver's licence obtained in Vienna, Austria in 2009. Is that Vienna driver's licence still valid?

Tags: driving-license

I have never requested a driver's permit in Albania as I am under the impression that the Vienna, Austria permit is valid in Albania. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, according to both on [Europa.EU](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/vehicles/driving-licence/driving-licence-recognition-validity/index_en.htm) and the UK's [Royal Auto Club (RAC)](https://www.rac.co.uk/drive/travel/country/albania/)

> Driving licences issued in EU and EEA countries are accepted. You will need an International Driving Permit, IDP 1949 to drive in Albania.
>
> Source: All information in this document is sourced from the AIT (Alliance Internationale de Tourisme) & the FIA (Federation Internationale de l'Automobile) and, to the best of the RAC’s knowledge, is correct at the time of publication (May 2016.)

As an official candidate for EU accession, Albania recognizes a driving licence issued by an EU country, but your national permit should be accompanied by an IDP, an identity document that allows you to drive in any country that recognises it, which Albania does.

The [Ministry of Transport and Infrastructure General Directorate of Road Transport Services](http://www.dpshtrr.gov.al/images/stories/dpshtrr/arkiva_ligjore/broshura_lejedrejtimi.pdf) is responsible for driving permits. Within its [website](http://www.dpshtrr.gov.al/sherbimet/per-drejtuesit-e-mjeteve/lejet-e-drejtimit/informacion-per-lejet/153-njevlefshmerite-e-kategorive-te-lejedrejtimit-), it references the EU licenses and their equivalencies, valid for driving in Albania (and please forgive the Google-lost-in-translation results).

And the Europa.eu expanded information on [EU driving licences](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/vehicles/driving-licence/driving-licence-recognition-validity/index_en.htm):

> If your driving licence is issued by an EU country, it's **recognised throughout the EU**.
>
> So if you move to another EU country, you won't usually have to exchange your licence. You can drive in your new country on your current licence as long as:
>
> - it is **valid**
> - you are old enough to drive a vehicle of the equivalent category
> - it is not **suspended** or **restricted** and has not been **revoked** in the issuing country.
>
> The **categories** AM, A1, A2, A, B, BE, B1, C1, C1E, C, CE, D1, D1E, D and DE are also recognised in other EU countries.
>
> **Standard format**
>
> Since 2013, all driving licences issued in the EU have a standard format – a **plastic, credit card-sized photocard**, with better security features.
>
> You can still use your old-style licence, but it will be changed to the new format when you renew it (or at the latest by 2033).
>
> There are over 110 European types of driving licence valid in the EU.
>
> **Validity in different EU countries**
>
> When your driving licence expires, you must renew it in the country where you have your usual residence.
>
> Your new licence may have a **different validity period** and will be subject to any restrictions or conditions that apply in your new country.
>
> **Recognition of EU driving licences issued in exchange for a non‑EU licence**
>
> If you have an EU driving licence that was issued in exchange for a non‑EU licence, and you wish to move to another EU country with your converted licence, you should be aware that your new licence **may not be recognised** there. This is up to each EU country.

Comment: I am not 100% sure this fully addresses the question as the RAC website is geared towards British tourists. For example, I looked up the rules for the Netherlands and it glosses over some niceties regarding situations in which holders of some EU licenses, e.g. from France, might be required to exchange their licenses (specifically, this could happen with a license issued over 10 years ago, which is still valid in France but must be exchanged against a newer one in the Netherlands, if you have been residing there for more than two years).

Comment: @Gala I'll add the Europe.EU info, which is longer; ty.